# Execute a script as root at boot on Fedora 15/16

Tags: linux, fedora, startup

I try to run a script (tpfand) at startup, and it asked to be root to execute it.

This is a script to control the fans on Thinkpad computers.

Despite several attempts, I could not get ...

Comment: [Have a look here, a blog post describing how to write service files](http://patrakov.blogspot.de/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html) for [`systemd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).  No idea why it shouldn't have one included already, though. ([...or use this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/tp-fan/+bug/776547))

Comment: Fedora 15/16 support ended ~3 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

The classic place to put one-off stuff like this was `rc.local`.

From the [Fedora 16 release notes](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Sysadmin.html):

> The `/etc/rc.d/rc.local local` customization script is no longer included by default. Administrators who need this functionality merely have to create this file, make it executable, and it will run on boot.

I'd say create `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/tpfand
```

and `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local` and you should be good to go.

Comment: It doesn't work...., un don't underwtand why... Maybe the tpfand works diferently

Comment: Can you confirm that just running `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` directly from command line does the right thing?