# Block network access of a process?

Tags: linux, networking, process, iptables

Is it possible to block the (outgoing) network access of a single process?

Comment: How do you intend to identify the process? PID, name, path?

Comment: What access do you want to block? Some programs use network access via `localhost` (to the same machine) to do their jobs.

Comment: See also [LD_PRELOAD or similar to prevent network access](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89044/ld-preload-or-similar-to-prevent-network-access), if the process is cooperating.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

With Linux 2.6.24+ (considered experimental until 2.6.29), you can use network namespaces for that. You need to have the 'network namespaces' enabled in your kernel (`CONFIG_NET_NS=y`) and util-linux with the [`unshare`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) tool.

Then, starting a process without network access is as simple as:

```
unshare -n program ...
```

This creates an empty network namespace for the process. That is, it is run with no network interfaces, including *no loopback*. In below example we add -r to run the program only after the current effective user and group IDs have been mapped to  the  superuser ones (avoid sudo):

```
$ unshare -r -n ping 127.0.0.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

If your app needs a network interface you can set a new one up:

```
$ unshare -n -- sh -c 'ip link set dev lo up; ping 127.0.0.1'
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=32 time=0.066 ms
```

Note that this will create a new, *local* loopback. That is, the spawned process won't be able to access open ports of the host's `127.0.0.1`.

---

If you need to gain access to the original networking inside the namespace, you can use [`nsenter`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) to enter the other namespace.

The following example runs `ping` with network namespace that is used by PID 1 (it is specified through `-t 1`):

```
$ nsenter -n -t 1 -- ping -c4 example.com
PING example.com (93.184.216.119) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=139 ms

--- example.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 134.621/136.028/139.848/2.252 ms
```

Comment: How do you block all programs by default, then start a specific program with network access (basically the opposite of what you show in your answer (share))?

Comment: I've added that to the answer :).

Comment: Thanks Michał Górny. I'm not exactly sure how that all works though. What I'm looking to do is to just boot my machine, and have all programs blocked from network access by default, with the ability to allow some (whitelist) to access the network. I think perhaps AppArmor might be suited for what I want to do.

Comment: `unshare -n` seems to throw "Operation not permitted" without `root` privileges, anything I missing about it?

Comment: To use it, you either need root privileges, or `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question...does this namespace also apply to child processes / called processes of the unshared application?

Comment: Yes. It is inherited by all children spawned after switching the namespace.

Comment: Perhaps instead of "new enough kernel" you can add in which kernel this feature was introduced. According to [this page](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NET_NS.html) it's either 2.6.24 or 2.6.29, so I guess 2.6.29 is a safe call.

Comment: I looks like any program that I'd like to unshare e.g. with `sudo unshare -n` inherits the root right. As I need the sudo to call unshare I'm wondering how I can make sure that the called program doesn't have the root rights.

Comment: How can I allow arbitrary outgoing network access except specifically for local, reserved or private access?

Comment: as best I could tell all children process inherited the network restriction so I was able to delevate myself using a bash shell and su `sudo unshare -n bash` then `sudo su <user>` and `ping localhost` from that shell was still unable to connect

Comment: sudo unshare -n ping 127.0.0.1
    unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: One liner to restrict process to a user. Just sudo twice: ```sudo unshare -n sudo -u dude bash -c 'echo Hello, my name is $USER'```
@ThorSummoner
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205240

Comment: `$ unshare -r -n ping 127.0.0.1` gives me 
`unshare: unshare failed: Invalid argument`. `$ unshare --version`
`unshare from util-linux 2.31.1`

Comment: @TomHale, check that network namespaces are enabled in your kernel.

Comment: For others wondering how, that's `$ sudo cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip -d | grep CONFIG_NET_NS`

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10 the command `unshare -n -- sh -c 'ip link set dev lo up; ping 127.0.0.1'` fails with the error message _unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted_ . By adding the `-r` flag the unshare command succeeds. Maybe `-r` is missing in the answer?

Comment: What abut `unshare -c -n ping 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: For me, `unshare -n bash` failed with permissions too, but `unshare -nU bash` works. This also hides the user namespace too, but that isn't a problem in my use case.

Answer (score 37):

Linux has a feature called [network namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/) which allow you to essentially have multiple network stacks on the same machine, and assign one to a program when running it. This is a feature typically used for containers, but you can also use it to accomplish what you want.

The [`ip netns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) subcommands manage it. Creating a new network namespace with no access to anything is easy, it's the default state of a new namespace:

```
root@host:~# ip netns add jail
```

Now, if you switch in to that namespace, you can configure it fairly easily. You'll probably want to bring up lo in it, and that's it:

```
root@host:~# ip netns exec jail /bin/bash
root@host:~# ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
root@host:~# ip link set dev lo up
root@host:~# exit
```

Now when you want to run your command with no network, you just run it in that jail:

```
root@host:~# ip netns exec jail su user -c 'ping  8.8.8.8'
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The network is, as desired, unreachable. (You can do all kinds of interesting things as a separate network stack includes `iptables` rules, etc.)

Comment: Although I needed `sudo ip` to execute the ip commands, once I was into bash, I just executed `su someuser` to get an unprivileged shell for user 'someuser'.

Answer (score 24):

**Solution 1: Unshare**

[Unshare](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) from util-linux package can start an application on a different namesapece without network but this require root firejail's solution do almost exactly the same thing but does not require root

```
unshare -r -n app-command
```

**Solution 2: Firejail:**

[Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com) can be used to block network access for an application this does not require root any user can benefit from it

```
firejail --noprofile --net=none app-command
```

**Solution 3: Systemd**

Since [Systemd v235](http://0pointer.net/blog/ip-accounting-and-access-lists-with-systemd.html) there is also another very easy option:

```
systemd-run --scope -p IPAddressDeny=any -p IPAddressAllow=localhost app-command
```

**Solution 4: Firewall:**

We could use firewalls like [Douane](https://douaneapp.com/) or [Opensnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) BUT those applications are not 100% efficient or in an early stage of development (have a lot of bugs etc. as of 2019)

**Solution 5: Kernel MAC:**

Kernel MACs can be used as a firewall most known are [Tomoyo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TOMOYO_Linux), [Selinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SELinux) and [Apparmor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AppArmor)
This solution is the best one when it come to stability and efficiency (firewall solution) but most of time setting this is somehow complicated.

**Solution 6: Proxify:**

One solution is to proxify the application to a **null/fake** proxy. We can use [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net) or [proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound). Here is some [details about the setup](https://www.binarytides.com/proxify-applications-with-tsocks-and-proxychains-on-ubuntu/)

**Solution 7: Iptables:**

An other easy solution is iptables, it could be setup to block an application

1. Create, validate *new group*; add required users to this group:

   - Create: `groupadd no-internet`
   - Validate: `grep no-internet /etc/group`
   - Add user: `useradd -g no-internet username`
     *Note: If you're modifying already existing user you should run: `usermod -a -G no-internet userName`
     check with : `sudo groups userName`*
2. Create a *script* in your path and make it executable:

- Create: `nano /home/username/.local/bin/no-internet`
- Executable: `chmod 755 /home/username/.local/bin/no-internet`
- Content: `#!/bin/bash`
                `sg no-internet "$@"`

3. Add *iptables rule* for dropping network activity for group *no-internet*:

   - `iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP`
     *Note: Don't forget to make the changes permanent, so it would be [applied automatically after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/execute-a-script-as-root-at-boot-on-fedora-15-16). Doing it, depends on your Linux distribution.*

4. Check it, for example on Firefox by running:
       
   * `no-internet "firefox"`

5. In case you would want to make an exception and allow a program to access *local network*:

- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP`

6. Make it permanent

One way to apply the iptables rule at boot is to add the rule as a service with systemd

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nonet.service
[Unit]
Description=Nonet group iptable update
After=network.target
After=xsession.target
After=iptables.service
After=shorewall.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/Scripts/Nonet.iptables.sh
```

Comment: This is a seriously excellent guide. Thank you. Although, for me, my no-internet command never seemed to pass the parameter, so I'm using `sg no-internet` for now.

Comment: @Zach i updated my answer you may be interested in firejail ;)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive overview, @intika. Note that `unshare` can be run without root, e.g., `unshare -Un program`. Tested in Mint 20.1/Linux 5.4.0-58/util-linux 2.34 and Debian 10.10/Linux 4.19.0-17/util-linux 2.33.1 (the latter required running `/usr/sbin/sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` to [enable unprivileged user namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617543/why-is-it-possible-to-create-other-namespaces-without-real-root-using-user-names#comment1157719_617543)).

Comment: @intika thank you for the information! Is there also a solution as Node.js module to be installed if I use sharing hosting and don't have permission to set up any of solutions you described?

Comment: @MilesWolbe doing that is generally a bad idea as it makes your kernel exploitable: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209529/what-does-enabling-kernel-unprivileged-userns-clone-do

Answer (score 22):

You could use iptables and move that process into a cgroup:

```
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/block
echo 42 > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/block/net_cls.classid

iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 42 -j DROP

echo [pid] > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/block/tasks
```

Comment: how to remove the pid out of that tasks file its giving error when i m trying to remove or delete data from that file though i m with root user

Comment: @pkm to enable networking back, you only need to echo [pid] to `/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks` (no 'block' in path)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, with customized apparmor profile, i.e

```
/usr/bin/curl {
    ...

    # block ipv4 acces
    deny network inet,
    # ipv6 
    deny network inet6,
    # raw socket
    deny network raw,

}
```

But in that way, you will need to generate a list of allowed files to access as well, the whole procedure can be a bit of complicated. And [see the help document here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor)

Comment: This would prevent incoming network access as well as outgoing.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [firejail sandbox](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail) (should work on kernels with seccomp feature).

To use it just do

```
firejail --noprofile --net=none <path to executable>
```

`--noprofile` disables default sandbox
`--net=none` disables networking

I do believe that most distros do provide package already but even if they don't firejail has virtually no dependencies other than build toolchain and namespace/seccomp enabled kernel.

There are some other nice features of firejail that can be shown with `firejail --help` with regards to networking (such as only providing loopback interface or blocking ip/dns etc) but this should do the job.
Also, it `doesn't require root`.

Comment: This also prevents app from connecting to dbus

Comment: To allow dbus, one can use something like this:- `firejail --ignore=protocol --protocol=unix vlc`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do it with iptables alone. This feature [briefly existed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/per-process-firewall), but couldn't be made to work reliably and was abandoned.

If you can run the process as a dedicated user ID, iptables can do it with the `owner` module:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1234 -j DROP
```

See examples in [Iptables: matching outgoing traffic with conntrack and owner. Works with strange drops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52404/iptables-matching-outgoing-traffic-with-conntrack-and-owner-works-with-strange), [iptables/pf rule to only allow XY application/user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12499/iptables-pf-rule-to-only-allow-xy-application-user)

If you can run the process in its own container, you can firewall that container independently (even make it completely disconnected from the network).

A security module can filter a process's access to networking features. [warl0ck's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process/68962#68962) gives an example with AppArmor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [seccomp-bpf](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt) to block some system calls. For example might want to [block the `socket`](https://github.com/randomstuff/randomstuff/blob/master/system/seccompstuff/nonetwork.c) system call in order to prevent the process from creating sockets FD.

I wrote an [example](https://github.com/randomstuff/randomstuff/blob/master/system/seccompstuff/nonetwork.c) of this approcah which prevents the `socket` system call for working using libseccomp. The summary is (without error checking):

```
scmp_filter_ctx ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW);
seccomp_arch_add(ctx, SCMP_ARCH_NATIVE);
seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ERRNO(EACCES), SCMP_SYS(socket), 1, SCMP_CMP(0, SCMP_CMP_EQ, pf));
seccomp_load(ctx);
execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
```

This does not need root privilegese.

A complete sandbox is much more complex however so you should not use this un order to block non-cooperative/malicious programs.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use this? Does it require root privileges to work?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what distro you're using but that's a feature usually included in the OS's MAC system. As stated previously Ubuntu or SuSE's AppArmor can do this. If you're using RHEL you can configure SELinux to either allow or deny access to a particular port number based on the executing process's label. [This](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-ad837f60830442ae77a81aedd10c20305a811388) is all I could find after some fast googling but there are probably more in depth resources online if you look harder and it gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Since Systemd v235 there is also another very easy option:

[IP Accounting and Access Lists with systemd](http://0pointer.net/blog/ip-accounting-and-access-lists-with-systemd.html)

> TL;DR: systemd now can do per-service IP traffic accounting, as well as access control for IP address ranges.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a command line program called "proxychains" and try one of the following possibilities:

Set it up that it uses...

- ...a proxy that does not exist? (I do not know if it will run it with an "invalid" proxy)
- ...a local proxy (like "tinyproxy", "squid", "privoxy",...) that limits access to the internet? (Just use ACLs)

I have not tested it myself so I do not know if it works...

Comment: Posting untested solutions generally isn't a good idea.

Comment: proxychains with a nonexisting proxy (like localhost:1234 or the like) might actually be a solid approach, however

Comment: @Twirrim, I hate this culture that answers need to be chewed and digested to be acceptable. This is knowledge share. drkhsh is not payed to do op's job. `proxychains` is a solid approach and unless anybody found it not working, it is stupid to downvote IMO. If you don't want to try it and don't like the answer, leave it unvoted. Downvotes are for wrong and inadequate answers.