# Any way to block UDP for a specific applcation

Tags: proxy, udp

Is there any way on Linux to block UDP traffic for a specific process. I tried using AppArmor deny of certain traffic, but it only supports total denial of all network access, not a specific protocol. I dont want to block all UDP for the system, just 1 process. Unfortunately this is because NodeJS applications love to restrict and control the ability of the user to modify the behavior of the application, short of them rewriting code.

Comment: `NodeJs ` run with its own user? Use the same source port for the udp traffic?

Comment: It uses the same destination port but if you block that port then it switches to random ports.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process take a look here

Comment: Using `unshare` as @YetAnotherUser suggests is a good way to jail  a process entirely from the network.  Giving it back some access (not all) after doing that is possible with `iptables` but may be complicated.  Consider using [docker](https://www.docker.com/) or similar container technology.  Containers basically manage the namespaces for you.  They can be a steep learning curve though.